# Grouped column is not going before pinned columns on the left - ag grid/react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, grid, ag-grid

So i have about 4 pinned columns on the left of my grid and at the moment, when i try to group a column, the automatic group column is going in the wrong place. I want it to go before the pinned columns on the left.
I added this to the column definitions -

```
  autoGroupColumnDef: {
        pinned: 'left',
        lockPinned: true,
      },
```

But this doesn't make a difference.
Is this a bug with ag grid?